# Documentation: how do I document that a function can return more than one type of variable?

Tags: php, documentation, phpdoc

Assume a PHP function like this:

```
/**
 * Description
 *
 * @return  Namespace\GenericObject
 */
function doSomething() {
    if ($some_parameter) {
        return new GenericObject;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

How should the `return` of the function be documented, using PHPDoc standard? As far as I know, a function should only have one `return` documented, yet, the function above can return either a new object, or a bool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the or `|` operator.

```
/**
 * Description
 *
 * @return  Namespace\GenericObject|null|array|false
 */
function doSomething() {
    if ($some_parameter) {
        return new GenericObject;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does `null|array` come from?

Comment: @AbraCadaver out of my head. It's an example. chill